# Within a given database: what objects cant have the same name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a given database what objects (Table, View, Index, Constraint, Trigger etc) can or can't have the same name?

So a table or view can have the same name if they are in a different schema. 
Is this true of other database objects?

For example, can an index have the same name of another if it is in another schema or for another table?

What are the rules for uniqueness around identifiers?
(Not what we should do or naming conventions, but rather what is valid to do)

Comment: A related question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731997/name-of-index-need-to-be-unique-in-database

Comment: Yes that is similar and answers specifically for index, but what about tiggers or constraints etc. I guess i am trying to find the rules which define the uniques of a of an database objects name within a database.

Comment: Sorry i was asking about it in a round about way